# Android Studio XML code is folding my code automatically

Tags: android, android-studio

i'm have a small problem with my android studio IDE, i've made some changes but don't remember exactly where i did made this change in the settings, the problem is that my xml code is always folded, and i want to know how i can change it to be unfolded by default as it should be.

[image]

Comment: On Mac, may try Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Code Folding -> XML, untick XML tags and apply.

Answer (score 2):

Preferences > Editor > General > Code Folding > XML > XML tags: disable

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

**For Android Studio 4.0 or above**

Goto Settings or Press (Ctrl + Alt + S)

And Navigate to Editor = > Code Folding

[image]

And uncheck the option XML tags
[image]